# Easiest way to generate random array from {1,-1} with predefined mean value in Numpy?

Tags: numpy, random

What is the best way in numpy to generate a random array with n values of the form

```
    arr = [1,-1,-1,1,1,1,...]
```

that average out as close as possible to a predefined value m, so that

```
    print 1/n*np.sum(arr)
    >>> #value that is as close as possible to m
```

I have been experimenting with

```
    numpy.random.choice([-1,1], size=n)
```

but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, recognize that for a fixed `n`, you can't (in general) choose the array whose mean is *exactly* an arbitrary value `m`.  I'll assume that either you are choosing `m` for which a solution is possible, or you are OK getting something close to the given mean.

The mean of `n1` 1s and `n2` -1s is `(n1 - n2) / n` where `n = n1 + n2`.  So you want `m = (n1 - n2) / n = (n1 - (n - n1)) / n = (2*n1 - n) / n = 2*n1/n - 1`.  This gives `n1 = (m + 1)*n/2` (which works for -1 <= `m` <= 1).  So you can create an array with `n1` 1s and `n - n1` -1s, and then randomize that array.

For example, suppose `n` is 100, and the desired mean is 0.8:

```
In [35]: n = 100

In [36]: m = 0.8
```

Compute the number of positive 1s:

```
In [37]: n1 = int(round((m + 1) * n / 2.0))  # rounded to the nearest int
```

Create the array of 1s and -1s:

```
In [38]: x = np.ones(n, dtype=int)

In [39]: x[:n-n1] = -1
```

Shuffle it:

```
In [40]: np.random.shuffle(x)

In [41]: x
Out[41]: 
array([ 1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,
        1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,
       -1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,
       -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1])

In [42]: x.mean()
Out[42]: 0.80000000000000004
```

Answer (score 4):

You can optionally enter probabilities values for each element in the array you pass to `random.choice`. In this case your average or expected value is p - q where p is probability of a positive one and q the probability of a negative. Note that this is independent of `n`. If you set the probability of a positive one to p then the probability of a negative one is 1 - p. You can then solve 2p - 1 = m to get the p-value you want for a given m.

For example, for your average m to be .4 you would pass [.7, .3] as the probabilities:

```
numpy.random.choice([1, -1], n, p=[.7, .3])
```

Here's an example:

```
In [25]:
n = 1e6
m = .4
p = (m + 1) / 2
np.random.choice([1, -1], n, p=[p, 1-p]).sum() / n

Out[25]:
0.39873799999999998
```